# Magento 2 add extra column in order grid using virtual type

Tags: magento2, custom-column-grid

Thanks! for view this post.
How to add custom column in order grid and what are the advantages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

please you can refer to below link.

https://store.magenest.com/blog/add-more-columns/